# Class not found error even with autoloading

Tags: php

I'm not a PHP expert; am trying to use this [TextRank Library](https://github.com/crodas/TextRank) to help with a project. 
I seem to be running into a bizarre issue: even after adding the autoload function, executing on the command line still results in "class not found" error. So here's the layout:

Code that calls the other classes (the "main" code):

```
echo realpath (__DIR__);
function __autoload($class_name) {
    if(file_exists(__DIR__ . "/lib/TextRank/" . $class_name . '.php')) {
        require_once(__DIR__ . "/lib/TextRank/" . $class_name . '.php');    
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.");
    }
}



$config   = new Config;
$textrank = new TextRank($config);

$keywords = $textrank->getKeywords("The only asynchronous, one-on-four game in Nintendo’s booth came from the “Wait, they’re still making that?” franchise that is Mario Party, and its buried presence didn’t bode well. Thankfully, Mario Party 10’s demo didn’t waste time with the series’ slowest crawl-around-a-board-game moments, instead jumping straight into four mini-games.");

var_dump($keywords);
```

Here's my directory structure:

- /test.php (the above file)
- /lib
- /lib/TextRank (contains all the classes referenced by the above code
- /lib/TextRank/Config.php

Yet, I still get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in /path/to/test.php
```

This means that:

1. The autoload is working, as no exceptions were thrown.
2. But somehow, PHP still isn't finding the required classes??

Does this have anything to do with the namespace conventions used in the classes, such as:

(in /lib/TextRank/Config.php)

```
namespace crodas\TextRank;

class Config
{
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. You need to do

```
$config = new crodas\TextRank\Config();
```

But that will not get catched by your autoloader. You need to look for an PSR-0 compatible autoloader.

Comment: You need to remove the crodas from the name or move the classes to another subfolder /lib/crodas/TextRank. Otherwise the PSR-0 cant do its work